# Difference between extending Activity vs AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using this extension function for view binding in my app activities:

```
inline fun <T : ViewBinding> Activity.viewBinding(crossinline bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater) -> T) = lazy(NONE) {
  bindingInflater.invoke(layoutInflater).also { setContentView(it.root) }
}
```

My BaseActivity extends from AppCompatActivity. Should I change the extension function to  AppCompatActivity.viewBinding... instead of Activity.viewBinding... ?

Does it make any difference?

Comment: For this, your code seems like it should work fine for `Activity`. `AppCompatActivity` inherits from `Activity`, so this extension function will work on anything that extends `AppCompatActivity` as well.

Comment: it works fine, yes, but it would it be more appropriate to use AppCompatActivity? or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Here, it does not matter. If you were doing something that needed functions or properties unique to `AppCompatActivity`, then you would need for your extension function to be on `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an opinion thing I think, but personally I think it's better to be as general as possible without losing too much meaning.

Like how it's better to use `List` as a type instead of `ArrayList`, because it doesn't rely on anything specific to `ArrayList`, and you want it to be usable on anything.

Whereas you might not want to make the type `Collection` even if it will work on all collections, just because you're encouraging the use of lists in this code, and generalising too much makes the intent and design a little harder to follow, possibly for no benefit!

So personally I'd probably just go with `Activity`, because that's what it operates on and it's clearer what the function is about - there's nothing specific to `AppCompatActivity` here, it's just about activities in general. But if you wanted to enforce the use of `AppCompatActivity` in the codebase (because you should be using it everywhere really) then this is another way to do it. Up to you!